# Add spatial index to versioned feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase

I try to add spatial index to versioned feature class (Oracle SDE) using toolbox "Add Spatial Index" in ArcGIS 10.6 . When I try it as Data owner I have error message -"Tool must be run as owner of SDE.Default version". But when I try to run it as SDE user I have error message "Tool must be run as Data owner".

So I am little bit confused. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

I can do this in ArcCatalog as Data Owner, but I need to run via toolbox as batch process.

Comment: It seems as if this question was asked recently (within day), and had useful comments. Did you ask that question? Where did it go?

Comment: Hi Vince, I asked that question, but only once. Without comments yet.